# How can I reset all ASP Profile Properties to their default value?

Tags: asp.net, properties, profile

How can I reset all the Profile Properties defined in the web.config to their default values?

So if for instance, I have in web.config the following definition:

```
<profile enabled="true">
    <properties>
        <add name="Number" type="System.Int32"  allowAnonymous="true" defaultValue="50"/>
<add name="Name" allowAnonymous="true" defaultValue="Tom"/>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

and in the C# code eventually, those values change to "15" and "George", how can I reset all the properties to their original values automatically, meaning without having to explicitly doing in C#:

```
Profile.Number = 50;
Profile.Name = "Tom";
```

Is there anything like Profile.Properties.Reset() or at least a way of looping through all the properties and reassigning their default value (I need a generic solution that's why I can't do one by one explicitly)

Thanks!

Comment: I think you would have to read and loop through the web.config file settings, but it would still be one-by-one, in C#.

Comment: Thanks but can you show me how to loop get the default value and set that value to each property?